# How do we add border to a datagrid?

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagrid which displays data read from an xml file.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(@"App_Data\Mediaplan.xml"));
            DataView dv = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "ActivityId=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            dg.DataSource = dv;
            dg.DataBind();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(dg); 

     }
```

My doubt is how do I add a border to this datagrid? I need a simple black border around the grid. If it can only be done in HTML side, plz let me know how. I am a new bee to .NET.
I am building an ASP.net web app using VS 2010.

Thanks in advance,
Pooja

Comment: The easiest way would be to wrap your table in a DIV and give it a border.  You'll only need to add 2 lines of code to your ASPX page.  Example (<div style="border: solid 1px #000"> <datagrid here></div>

Comment: Since I am adding this datagrid to a PlaceHolder, I think I can add div tag only to Placeholder like this. <div style="border: solid 1px #000"> <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> </div> But that doesnt seem to be an appropriate way, coz the border gets displayed even beofre the grid gets populated , Also the datagrid occupies only a part of place holder, where as the border is for the entire thing. Any thing else I can follow here?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the border to datagrid by providing the BorderColor, BorderWidth attributes to the Datagrid.

Here is the example......

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dg1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2px" 
            CellPadding="0">

      </asp:DataGrid>
```

If you are defining in code behind then try this adding in code behind.

```
dg1.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(2);
dg1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Comment: The datagrid is declared in the code behind DataGrid dg = new DataGrid(); So I dont see an HTML definition for it, The placeholder is used to integrate the datagrid, Any thing else I can do here?

Comment: PLease check i have edited for the code behind also. If still you have problem please tell...